# Saving and loading Docker images on local disk

Tags: python, docker, image

I downloaded a Docker image from a repo and it´s now stored as a local image.
How do I save the changes to a new local image which can be loaded just like the previous original image?

**I run it like this in cmd:**
docker run --ipc=host --rm --gpus all -it --name devtest --mount type=bind,source="C:/Users/myname/RV/RV_CODE_DIR",target=/opt/src/code --mount type=bind,source="C:/Users/myname/RV/RV_OUT_DIR",target=/opt/data/output --mount type=bind,source="C:/Users/myname/RV/RV_DATA_INPUT_DIR",target=/opt/data/data_input quay.io/azavea/raster-vision:pytorch-0.20 /bin/bash

**Make changes:**
pip install --force-reinstall torch==1.12.1+cu113 --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/

I wish to save it as a new image after my pip install